# BootstrapError Form

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5

I'm getting this error in my template:

> Exception Value: Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import CustomerProfile

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerProfile
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'phone', 'business')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'business': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

In my views.py I did this:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import CustomerForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'landingpage/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'landingpage/about.html')

def new_contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('landingpage:thanks'))
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()

    return render(request, 'landingpage/index.html', {'form': form})


def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'landingpage/thanks.html')
```

My index.html form section:

```
<!-- Contact Section-->
        <section class="page-section" id="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Contact Section Heading-->
                <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0">Contact Me</h2>
                <!-- Icon Divider-->
                <div class="divider-custom">
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                    <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Contact Section Form-->
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                            <form action="{% url 'landingpage:index' %}" method="post" class="form">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% bootstrap_form form %}
                                {% buttons %}
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl enabled" id="submitButton" type="submit">Send</button>
                                {% endbuttons %}

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Any ideas?
I've tried a lot of changes, but were none has solved the problem.
Has someone get stuck into this, already?

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: The variable `fields` in the forms.py file must be a list, so try changing the parentheses with brackets, so you have: `fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'business']`

Comment: Also try taking out the `%` in the template `{% bootstrap_form form %}`  when calling a form into your template you should write `{{ form }}`

Comment: Nice. I don't get the error anymore, but the form doesn't show up when I run the template in local host

Answer (score 0):

In your template change

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

to

```
{{ form }}
```

You should documente yourself on how to use variable in template and also how to render form : [Django Form Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: Nice. I don't get the error anymore, but the form simply doesn't show up when I run the template in local host.

Comment: My templates sourcecode is based on this theme: https://startbootstrap.com/theme/freelancer
I'm changing the default form by the one in my app.